# using environment variables in service script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, init

I am facing an issue using environment variables in my service script.

In my services script, i am using an environmental variable i.e. INSTALL_DIR whose value may vary on different system. I have to get the installation directory from $INSTALL_DIR and then i have to start the service. when i am running the service script the environment variable is not sourced at all.

Is it possible to source the installation directory from INSTALL_DIR environment variable. another option i can think is dynamically creating the service script using INSTALL_DIR environment variable.

```
echo "INSTALL DIR: ${INSTALL_DIR}"
name=`basename $0`
pid_file="/var/run/$name.pid"
get_pid() {
    cat "$pid_file"
}

is_running() {
    [ -f "$pid_file" ] && ps `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}

Start()
{
    echo "Starting Application"

    if is_running; then
        echo "[`get_pid`] Already Started"
    else
        if [ -z "$user" ]; then
            nohup $INSTALL_DIR/bin/application 2>&1 &
        else
            nohup sudo -u "$user" $cmd 1> $INSTALL_DIR/bin/application 2>&1 &
        fi
        echo $! > "$pid_file"
        if ! is_running; then
            echo "Unable to start, see logs"
            exit 1
        fi
        echo "[`get_pid`] Started"
    fi
}
```

I am trying to run the application using following command

```
service application start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my services script ... I have to get the installation directory from $INSTALL_DIR and then i have to start the service.

Your question isn't really about shell scripting, but about your system's startup.  Unfortunately that process varies by Linux distribution, and tends to be poorly documented.

For example, **man service** says, *service runs a System V init script or upstart job in as predictable an environment as possible, removing most environment variables  and  with the current working directory set to /.*, but **man upstart** says:

```
$ man -k upstart
upstart: nothing appropriate.
```

Not only that, but the **service** manpage specifically lists the environment variables a script will start with.  Needless to say, yours isn't among them.

The traditional approach to parameterizing startup scripts is to put the information in a known file, normally in `/etc`, and reference that file in the script.  In your case, you could do something like:

```
INSTALL_DIR=$(cat /etc/my-install-dir.cfg)
```

and then proceed accordingly.

There might be ways to coerce your startup to support other environment variables.  But, sooner or later, the information you need has to be stored somewhere on the filesystem.  It seems to me the simplest approach is to reserve a filename to hold that information, and read that file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code in your script.

```
if [[ -z "${INSTALL_DIR}" ]]; then
  echo "INSTALL_DIR is undefined"
else
  INSTALL_DIR=<<your installation directory>>
fi
```

Comment: if i do like this, install directory is not sourced when i use "service application start"

Comment: Then export $INSTALL_DIR value in ~/.bash_rc or ~/.profile file.